# Reformatting values in a pandas row into associated columns

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe which looks like:

```
ID1 ID2 Issues  Value1  Value2  IssueDate
1   1   1   56.85490855 9.489650847 02/12/2015
1   1   2   89.55441203 23.60227363 07/02/2015
1   2   1   21.8456428  23.37353082 01/10/2015
2   2   1   55.10795933 1.928443984 13/08/2015
2   2   2   10.22459873 24.44298882 07/04/2015
4   1   1   55.29748656 6.308424035 19/02/2015
```

and I want it to be multiple dataframes (this is Value1, but imagine a second for 2) which looks like:

```
Value 1                                                     
            2015_1  2015_2  2015_3  2015_4  2015_5  2015_6  2015_7I 2015_8  2015_9  2015_10 2015_11 2015_12
ID1 ID2
1   1           89.55441203                                     56.85490855
1   2                                           21.8456428      
2   2                   10.22459873             55.10795933             
4   1           55.29748656
```

The only way I can work out how to do this is to use a lambda function and add values in specific ranges to the associated columns. The problem is that my dataset is very large and trying to complete this movement line by line looping for each possible month/year combination will take a very long period of time.

Is there clever way to use masks or melts to reformat the data into the tables I am looking for?

Comment: what is the expected output ?

Comment: Look at pivot :-)

Comment: @GhilasBELHADJ the expected output is the second dataframe shown. I am looking to convert the first to the second.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you are looking for something like this

```
df.IssueDate = pd.to_datetime(df.IssueDate)
df['Date'] = df.IssueDate.dt.year.astype(str) + '_' + df.IssueDate.dt.month.astype(str)
pd.pivot_table(df[['ID1', 'ID2', 'Value1', 'Date']], columns='Date', index=['ID1', 'ID2'])
```

Comment: This was the answer I was looking for, I had to do some reset_indexing, to get the headers as I'd like. Specifically pivoted_data['Value1'].reset_index() to get rid of the hierarchal indexing

Comment: I'm glad that I could help you :-)